# Launching EIP using Terraform in AWS Local Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

AWS introduced Local Zone in us-west-2 region which created a new variable network border group while creating EIP. In terraform I am unable to launch the EIP in the us-west-2-lax-1 network border group.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip

Is there a way to launch EIP using terraform in AWS local zone us-west-2-lax-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Terraform 0.13 provides support for network border group attribute while creating an EIP.